# How does the connection between the deployment groups target machine agent and VSTS server work?

Tags: azure-devops

I've recently stumbled across VSTS deployment groups as a solution for CI/CD for a console application that runs on several machines with Windows 10 OS (not azure hosted).

I was able to create a proof of concept that deployment groups are a great solution for our particular situation and I am trying to find out more in-depth details on the communication between the VSTS server and the agent running on the target machine in order to provide details on security concerns. I've gone through the documentation provided by MS but I haven't been able to find/understand how the communication between the 2 is done in terms of protocol, ports used and any other possible relevant details.

The agent is running in interactive mode (not as a service).

**I've tried the following:**

1. Using Fiddler to track the HTTP/HTTPS requests done during the entire release process on the target machine - no HTTP/HTTPS requests seem to be made during this time.
2. Using TCP View reveals a TCP connection established between the target machine and the VSTS server once the agent is started. The connection is started by the AgentListener.exe process. However, whenever a new connection is established (the agent is restarted), this creates a new TCP connection on a different local port (it never seems to be the same local port).

Does anyone have more information on how this connection between the target machine and the VSTS server works?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Cece Dong, I was hoping for more than one answer before marking one as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Communication happens from the target machine to the VSTS/TFS via HTTP or HTTPS. If it is VSTS always port 443 outgoing is used from the target agent. and if it is TFS default 8080 is the port.  But the VSTS/TFS will not communicate to agent. Agent will communicate, and if any jobs, then will start execute downloading the content from server. This is referred to as pull model (Similar to a polling tentacle in octopus). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/agents?view=vsts#communication

Comment: "Similar to a polling tentacle in octopus" - @ChamindaC thank you for the comparison, this is really useful. I've read about the ports on the VSTS server side, but I am wondering if I need any ports opened on the target machine side. From what you are telling me, it would seem like I don't.

Comment: @Florinache Yes you do not need to open any port in target machine